# Организация запроса Last.FM

Tags: json, get, retrofit, интерфейс

коллеги!
Продолжаю работать с форматом json. И если уже есть навык работы непосредственно с файлами, которые есть явно в адресе запроса, то в следующем запросе мне немного непонятно как я обращаюсь к файлу. Вот пример запроса на Last.FM:

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=2b35547bd5675d8ecb2b911ee9901f59&format=json

Создаю интерфейс:

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface LastFMApiInterface {

```
String LASTFMURL = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/";
String API_KEY = "2b35547bd5675d8ecb2b911ee9901f59";
```

Что писать в методе GET???

```
@GET("????")
Call<String> getString();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET    
getString(@Query("method") String method, @Query("artist") String artist ....)
```

Comment: Т.е., я так понимаю, запрос расписывается полностью, исходя из структуры?